# jsPDF to show iframe in ANY IE versions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jspdf

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf#

http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Both resources ^ work fine in chrome and firefox, but the iframe generating the preview won't work in any version of IE for me. Anyone have any work-arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way I've found after dealing with both iframe and object/embed attempts, is through http://pdfobject.com/ .

Works in all IE v9+, Chrome, FireFox browsers.